# Weird table column positioning using fixed column

Tags: html, css

I have a dashboard that I'm working on that contains a table of width 100%. Under normal usage, the table has more columns than screen real estate and the dashboard scrolls through the results. However, under a new requirement, I only show selected servers. This is where I discovered my issue.

The table has a number of columns, but the main left handed column lists each row and is positioned absolutely on the left hand side of the page. I have attached some sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.headercol {
    position:absolute;
    width: 15%;
    left: 0;
    top: auto;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<body style="height: 90%">
<table style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid blue;">
<tr>
    <td style="width: 200px;" class="headercol">asdf</td>
    <td style="width: 200px;">adsf</td>
    <td style="width: 200px;">adsf</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, under this organization, all columns in the table that are not headercol now become right justified creating a huge space in the middle of the table. I would like them to return to their left justified positions. Does anyone know of a work around for this? The layout goes back to normal when not using the `position:absolute`, but  then we lose our fixed column. This is not an issue under normal conditions where there are columns to make up for the blank space in the table. This behavior was noted in both IE11 and Firefox 32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up floating all of the TD's over to the left and specifying an offset of the static column for the 2nd column. After that the remaining columns just `float: left` and all was well. An odd way of doing things, but it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so if you are using a stabile width for each `<td>` and `position: absolute;` in the first one, so you can do the same for the rest of the `<td>`.
And maybe get rid of `<table>` and use `<div>` instead, it will be easier and better :)